# Generate Reports with dynamic content and styling

Tags: c#, jsp, reporting

We are developing an application which also has to generate user-specific reports.

We have some projects in JSP and some in C# WPF. Our current requirement is to generate reports from the JSP application.

The template in these reports have different style attributes, such as:

- Having a Checkbox in the PDF generated
- Providing background color for a table cell
- Vertically oriented text
- A few shapes (such as line, triangle, etc) at some places

The data in these reports is dynamic, and is obtained as a Data Set from the database.

Can anyone please suggest me which API/tool is ideal to do these tasks? All the while we have been using XSL-FO and I personally feel, it is too much effort for just one report generation.

Is there any tool which is language/domain independent? (So that we could use it in all our Java/C# applications)

If not, let me know the best tool/API to generate reports from JSP application.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing two separate problems.  I don't have an opinion on middleware, but for presentation I prefer to use http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/ with some custom code.