# properly framework for dynamic reports

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, report

Thx for reading my question. I wanna ask if is it possible to create dynamic reports. By dynamic i mean:

1 - User can choose the columns

2 - User can choose the Grouping based on columns chosen above

3 - User can filter the report, based on columns chosen above

Nowadays, we use access as our tool. But we have many clients, so is very hard to maintain, change and design all these reports. We spend a lot of our time doing this job.

I found this question below, but didnt find anything useful

[Generate Reports with dynamic content and styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054758/generate-reports-with-dynamic-content-and-styling)

UPDATE: Example: I have one table, tab_client, where i found client information. I wanna pull idCliente, clientName, clientState, clientCity. The user can choose the group information between clientCity and clientState.

With only this information, with no previous layout, no rpt(crystal), no rldc(ssrs) file. The layout output should be like this:

State 1

```
     idClient clietName clientCity
         1         ABBC      3
         2         AACA      1
```

State 2

```
     idClient clientName clientCity
         3         Abc       3
         4         cba       2
```

*obs: Remember, no previous layout defined.

Best Regards

Comment: Using Crystal Reports you can do many things and among them, the things that you want. Most of the time you have to use designer with typed datasets.

Comment: Sry, i updated an example, its easier to understand now ; D

Comment: what about this from crystal reports website that allows you to change the values while inside crystal report viewer at runtime:http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/109e0473-8c2a-2d10-d195-8eba1badf7df&overridelayout=true

Comment: You can change the values from the viewer while viewing the report. view the last 2 minutes of the video when he is not in visual studio anymore and you can see the final view of the report.

Comment: Jeffery, could your post your comment as an answer, so i could vote it up. Thx u so much, i have been searching for this feature for the last few hours. Thx man ; D

Comment: I wanna ask for another tip. Do you know any link that teach how to do that grouping with coding, in c# or vb.net. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports with RAS can do it. RAS API can be used within Vs 2010 to implement runtime report changes.

Here you can find multiple links to many code examples:

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1006689

I wanna thx to Jeffery for giving the initial tip.